# Mongoose .find() returns an empty array when searching by enum field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
const SoundSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    minFrec: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    maxFrec:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    minInt:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    maxInt:{
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        required: true,
        enum: ["Hogar", "Naturaleza", "Conversación", "Ocio", "Lugares", "Ciudad"]
    }
});
```

And I am trying to create this route to show all my items that match a certain category:

```
app.get("/sounds/:category", async (req, res) => {
const sounds = await Sound.find({ category: 'Ocio' }).sort({ name: 'asc'});
res.render("sounds/category", { sounds });
});
```

It does not work (returns an empty array) but it works if I filter by something without "enum" (name, minInt, etc).

I have done other routes that work, and I can find those items in mongo `(db.sounds.find({category: "Ocio"}))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your schema define the field `category` as `lowercase: true` which means the string will be saved in lower case ([docs](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bIy-E3rSb82))

So you have to use lowercase into your query to match the exact value.

```
const sounds = await Sound.find({ category: 'ocio' }).sort({ name: 'asc'});
```

Or something more global:

```
const sounds = await Sound.find({ category: req.params.category.toLowerCase() }).sort({ name: 'asc'});
```

Even another option is to use `$regex` with option `i` like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bIy-E3rSb82) but it is a much more expensive option considering that your schema ensures that the field is lowercase. So to use `toLowerCase()` is a better option.